# How to determine window that calls function on another window in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm struggling with a complex problem in JavaScript: Is there any way to determine which window did call a function on another window? Consider a website `a.com/foo` which embeds an iframe loaded from `a.com/bar`. Both frames are same-origin, thus have access to each other's global window object.

Now, the iframe running on `a.com/bar` calls the function `foo`, globally scoped on its parent window. Is there any way to determine inside the `foo` function that it was called by the iframe? In specific, I need a reference to the iframe's window from within the `foo` function.

There are two restrictions:

1. We cannot change the function call in `window.parent.foo()`, as we cannot make changes to the source code on `a.com/bar`.
2. We cannot simply run `window.frames[0]` in the `foo` function to get a reference, as there are many iframes and we need to know which iframe called the `foo` function (in this case, the iframe on `a.com/bar`).

```
// a.com/foo embeds a.com/bar as iframe

// Running on a.com/foo
window.foo = function() {
    // window.location.href = "a.com/foo"
    // Q: How to get a reference to caller's window (the iframe on a.com/bar)?
}

// Running on a.com/bar
window.parent.foo(); // This call is fix, we cannot make changes in this iframe.
```

Any help or ideas are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Have a great day!

Comment: When does the iframe call the parent windows function? Is user interaction involved? If so, maybe [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement) may help you to avoid the loop.

Comment: No, you cannot, and no, a function should not care about its caller. What do you need this for? Use arguments and return values to communicate with the caller.

Comment: Actually, I do not know when the iframe calls the parent window's function, it is just done randomly inside the iframe. I need this for some Chrome extension I'm writing for test purposes. I know that under normal circumstances, there is no legitimate use case where this is needed. That's why I cannot change the callers, but I can change the callee by overwriting / wrapping its function.